# google play console discriminatory policy

Tags: console, playback, policy

I have got masters degree in IT and Computer Science (in particular software engineering).
I am Java developer since 1999. Working on particular software project since 2006.
Currently I am at the stage of publishing my app on Google Play Console.
The problem which I experienced is that Google collected money for my account and are stubborn of rejecting my passport as ID confirmation. I complained about it to Google but they said they are not competent enough to do anything and ignored it,
I do believe they are rejecting my passport because it was issued in Polish Embassy in London but my bank details are UK bank. I have got right to work and reside in the UK and it is nobody's problem that I born in Poland. So I have to fight with nasty ignorants. What should I do.

Hi Radoslaw,

Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.
I'm happy to help you with issues related to publishing and distributing apps through the Play Console.

At this time, my team isn't able to provide support for ID verification issues. I forwarded your question to the appropriate team at Google, and you can expect to hear from them soon.

If you have questions about using the Play Console, please let me know.

Regards,
Gaige
Google Play Developer Support

and now waiting forever!!!

Comment: We're you able to solve this issue?